# items in listview using holder mixed up

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have an issue with BaseAdapter of a simple list view.
I want to use a holder in getView method to get better performance in the list view.
BUT when i use the holder the items get all mixed up. the number of the items in the listview is right but the order is wrong.
thanks in advance.
this is my code inside the getView :

```
    ChatRowView holder;
    ChatActivity.chatObject currentChatObject = getItem(position);
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ChatRowView();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_row, null);
        holder.chatComponent = new ChatComponent(mContext, currentChatObject.isLeft, currentChatObject.extraType, currentChatObject.message);           

        holder.chatComponent.tvName.setText(currentChatObject.name);
        holder.chatComponent.tvTime.setText(currentChatObject.time);
        load("some picture", holder.chatComponent.ivUser);

        if(currentChatObject.extraType != ExtraContentView.eChatExtraContentType.NONE)
        {
            if(currentChatObject.extraType != ExtraContentView.eChatExtraContentType.GAME)
            {
                App.loadImage(teamsBaseUrl + "132" + "_70x70.png", holder.chatComponent.extraContentView.ivTeamLogo);
            }
            else
            {
                App.loadImage(teamsBaseUrl + "132" + "_70x70.png", holder.chatComponent.extraContentView.ivHomeTeamLogo);
                App.loadImage(teamsBaseUrl + "132" + "_70x70.png", holder.chatComponent.extraContentView.ivAwayTeamLogo);
            }
        }
        ((RelativeLayout)convertView).addView(holder.chatComponent);        
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        extraButtonsListener(holder.chatComponent);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ChatRowView)convertView.getTag();
    }                   
    return convertView;
```

Answer (score 0):

you missunderstood the usage of the `viewHolder` pattern. It was thought for efficiency reasons, in order to avoid the `findViewById` operation evertytime you scroll. The set* operations have to be done always. Given your implementation you should see always the same values (the first)

Answer (score 0):

Only use getView to recycle views , the attributes should be reset in this case. The Ui elements like TextView etc can be reused but the text in the textview should be reset even if convertview is not null. Try out the change outlined below

```
  ChatRowView holder;
ChatActivity.chatObject currentChatObject = getItem(position);
if(convertView == null)
{

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_row, null);

}


holder = new ChatRowView();  

   holder.chatComponent = new ChatComponent(mContext, currentChatObject.isLeft,        currentChatObject.extraType, currentChatObject.message);           

    holder.chatComponent.tvName.setText(currentChatObject.name);
    holder.chatComponent.tvTime.setText(currentChatObject.time);
    load("some picture", holder.chatComponent.ivUser);

    if(currentChatObject.extraType != ExtraContentView.eChatExtraContentType.NONE)
    {
        if(currentChatObject.extraType != ExtraContentView.eChatExtraContentType.GAME)
        {
            App.loadImage(teamsBaseUrl + "132" + "_70x70.png", holder.chatComponent.extraContentView.ivTeamLogo);
        }
        else
        {
            App.loadImage(teamsBaseUrl + "132" + "_70x70.png", holder.chatComponent.extraContentView.ivHomeTeamLogo);
            App.loadImage(teamsBaseUrl + "132" + "_70x70.png", holder.chatComponent.extraContentView.ivAwayTeamLogo);
        }
    }
    ((RelativeLayout)convertView).addView(holder.chatComponent);        
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    extraButtonsListener(holder.chatComponent);

return convertView;
```